# How does the WITH clause know which table to work with?

Tags: sql

I came across the following SQL statement in a book:

```
WITH dcount AS
(
    SELECT deptno, COUNT(*) AS dcount
    FROM employees
    GROUP BY deptno
)
SELECT 
    e.lname EMP_lastname,
    e.deptno e_dept,
    d1.dcount edept_count,
    m.lname manager_name,
    m.deptno mdept,
    d2.dcount mdept_count
FROM 
    employees e,
    dcount d1,
    employees m,
    dcount d2
WHERE 
    e.deptno = d1.deptno
    AND e.mgr = m.empno
    AND m.deptno = d2.deptno
    AND e.mgr = 7839
```

The purpose of the statement is to display an employees name, the department they work in, the number of coworkers in the department, the manager's name, and the number of people in the manager's department.

The part that confuses me is where it says d1.count and d2.count. How is it counting different things if the count is based on the same WITH statement?

Comment: The part that confuses me is that the statement starts with `FROM`.  This is not valid SQL code as written.

Comment: Sorry, first part of statement got cut off

Comment: The column names in the select should belong to one and only one of the tables from in the query body, unless differentiated by the alias. If not, every DBMS I've ever worked with (many) will return an error saying something along the lines of "dcount is ambiguous .. yada..yada". So as written, if this query actually runs mdept_count, d1, and d2 will all be the same. Might be an error in the text.

Comment: The query runs and produces results. This is with SQL Developer.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**almost 30 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 2):

The main query is joining the **same** CTE but is using different joining predicates each time:

- It's joining `d1` using `e.deptno = d1.deptno`.
- It's joining `d2` using `m.deptno = d2.deptno`.

Therefore each resulting row is picking a different row from the CTE.

Comment: Is the WITH clause executing first though, or is it treated more like a function call and is calculated each time it is referenced in the main query?

Comment: @The_Redhawk None of the above. SQL is a declarative language not an imperative one. It's up to the database engine to decide how to run the query. This can change on each and every execution. Moreover, the engine is free to rephrase the whole query to inline it (and to make it disappear altogether). All dirty tricks are on the table. You can get the execution plan of the query if you want to learn what the engine is planning to do [this time].

Comment: I was under the impression that certain parts of a statement are given precedence, such as a WHERE clause being examined before a GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @The_Redhawk I don't think there's merit to that idea. Where did you read that? I guess it could be an introductory material in a databases course, but real world engines don't work like that.

Comment: The book is "Oracle 12c: SQL" by Joan Casteel. The line in the book is: "When a SELECT statement includes all three clauses, the order in which they're evaluated is as follows, WHERE, GROUP BY, HAVING." The theme of the chapter was Group Functions.